# How to test StorPerf in Devstack?

Tags: devstack

I have installed Devstack(Rocky version) and installed Yardstick on my PC.

When I want to test Storperf(Storage Performance) manually and see the result. what are all the step by step procedure that I have to follow?

I have gone through the below link but not sure how to configure and test Storperf. https://wiki.opnfv.org/display/storperf/Storperf